# How to style forms using jQuery Mobile on a website

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

1. How can I use jQuery Mobile to style my forms? None of the other
   form styles look as cool.
2. Will it cause any conflict with jQuery plugins (i.e. cycle, validate, etc.)
   or cause conflict for anything else on my site?
3. Also is there any way to just use the form part of jQuery Mobile?

PS: I know UI is coming up with it in version 2.0 but it's still a few months away, so don't suggest it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery Mobile will cause no conflicts with jquery plugins (well, almost), but it will try to override the way the page is constructed, so it won't look like it did upto now. 
You cannot use JQM without it rebuilding your interface to some extent. You have been warned.

But despite that - I belive you can make it work with your forms and style the site as well.

important tip:
`<div data-role="page">` is now optional and you want it to be. Try not to use JQM's wrappers - it might make less changes to how the rest of the site looks

Comment: thanks. "Try not to use JQM's wrappers" what are they. Also i thought by just applying classes for inputs i will get the desired effect am i right here or i i will have to do something else too

Comment: Wrappers are the `page` `header` etc. data roles. But if you only need some JQM classes, then using its CSS only is quite a nice idea. You could download from git and get only the forms CSS from repo

Comment: so if just copy the css into my project i should be able to style checkbox, radio button, select(dropdowns) right. Also will i have to include the JQM js or copying only css is fine

Comment: You only need the CSS. You might have to set some class on form or some wrapper for the CSS to work. And I recommend taking only CSS for forms from repo. it's few percent of the size of the whole thing