# Can I use jquery Mobile for creating a Deskop browser based web applications?

Tags: jquery, web-applications, jquery-mobile, desktop-application

I just liked the declarative approach of jQuery Mobile! 
It is a good option to use jQuery Mobile for creating desktop sized web applications? 
What are the challenges and opportunities involved?

It is a webapp framework which seems compatible to iPad and likes, iPhone and likes and modern desktop browsers too!

Comment: It's fine 

Look at the following article http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348509/hows-the-idea-to-style-forms-using-jquery-mobile-on-a-normal-website

Comment: thanks ! seems doable with "care" ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fine Look at the following article [How to style forms using jQuery Mobile on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348509/hows-the-idea-to-style-forms-using-jquery-mobile-on-a-normal-website).

You can use without any major problem but i would recommend it only for tablet and modules though